# where can I find the source code for tftp (Trivial File Transfer Protocol)?

Tags: tftpd

where can I find the source code for tftp (Trivial File Transfer Protocol) ?

Answer (score 1):

tftp is a protocol and not a piece of software. It has no source code itself but there are many open source implementations available.

Answer (score 1):

TFTP is a protocol. The specification is available in [RFC 1350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350).

If you want source code for an implementation, a Google search for "tftp source code" finds a lot of answers, among them [TFTP].

Answer (score 0):

tftp-server package of CentOS / Fedora / RHEL is based upon:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/network/tftp/